# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError in jinja ( for loop isnt ended even though i wrote {% endfor %} in the code)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

this error is always coming even though i closed the for loop :

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

my python version is python3.6, flask version is 1.0.6 and jinja 2 version is 2.10

please see these code and help me

flask code:

```
from flask import *
import pandas
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    test = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
    test0 = test['PassengerId']
    test1 = test['Name']
    print(test0, test1)
    return render_template('index.html', tables={'test':test0,'test1':test1})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

templates/index.html :

```
{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>pandas app</title>
</head>
{% block body %}
    {% for test0,test1 in tables %}
        <TABLE>
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>PassengerId</th>
         <th>Name</th> 
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr>
          <td>{{ test0 }}</td>
          <td>{{ test1 }}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </TABLE>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

please help me ,any help is appreciated

thanks

Comment: The newest flask version is 1.0.2

Comment: The template looks like valid one

Comment: Hey mate, why you importing all the methods from flask it bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can block multiple blocks at once, so separate them:

```
{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>pandas app</title>
</head>

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% for test0,test1 in tables %}
        <TABLE>
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>PassengerId</th>
         <th>Name</th> 
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr>
          <td>{{ test0 }}</td>
          <td>{{ test1 }}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </TABLE>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```